# Access section header button in tableview when user clicks on a row of that section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to access a button of a section header when user clicks on row in `tableview`. I can get clicked row number and that particular section by using `NSIndexpath` (i.e. section 1 - row 0 etc.), but could not retrieve button in the section header. I've tried using `isKindOfClass` by iterate through `tableview`, but did not work.

```
    MainTableViewCell *clickedResourceCell = (MainTableViewCell*)btn.superview.superview;
    clickedResourceCell.customThresholdBar.value = slider.value/100;
    NSIndexPath *indexpath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:clickedResourceCell];

    [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%@", [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[(UISlider *)sender value]] intValue], @"%"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.sliderValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%@", [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[(UISlider *)sender value]] intValue], @"%"];
```

I've got row's button updated.Now want to update section.I've tried like this!

```
for(UIView *view in [self.tableView subviews])
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *bttn = (UIButton *)view;
            if (bttn.titleLabel.tag == 7) {
                if (bttn.tag == indexpath.section) {
                    NSLog(@"FOUND");
                    [bttn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%@", completedAmount/i, @"%"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show some code or provide some more info of what have you tried.

Comment: Hi,Puneet I've added the code snippt! Note: I reloaded tableview but it also did not worked. After reloading tableview it always sets to NSIndexpath to section 0 - row 0. Thats why Im trying use this solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
UIView *sectionHeader = [tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section]; 
UIButton *button = (UIButton*)[sectionHeader viewWithTag:<button's tag>];
```

whenever you have the indexpath of the row.
Good Luck!

Comment: Hi Fahri, thank you for quick reply.I dont know why it still not working. Im using custom header view and it has several buttons! Any ideas?

Comment: Hello. Do you set tags for each button on the header? if not, then when you are creating buttons, set tag to each button like so: `button.tag = 'int_tag_value'`. And later you can get that button like in the example I have posted.